# Подскажите с позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Помогите советом как сделать дугу как на скрине? И как реализовать положение картинки на втором скрине? Никак не могу сообразить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: один из вариантов: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLVNrGB

Comment: это этот чувак: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvoaZLN

Comment: Отлично! Я svg как-то не брал в расчет хотел чисто на css реализовать.

Comment: на css с чуваком не знаю как - не пробовал - как видите есть проще методы чем писать кучу after/before а по поводу девочки - то  радиальный градиент должен помочь

Comment: а можете пример показать с градиентом? заранее спасибо

Comment: на градиенте: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/poNjNdg

Comment: svg конечно интереснее

Comment: естественно ... я по этому исключил вариант на css и сразу написал на SVG

Comment: в cvg можно подробнее за что отвечают эти параметры d="M0,100 C0,100 450,0 900,100 L900,500 0,500z"? я внедрил в верстку но видно что немного кривовато

Comment: а ребята получились шикарно http://joxi.ru/GrqnJdPCGKayWm

Comment: это точки от верхнего левого угла ..

Comment: `c` это кубическая кривая

Comment: рисует дугу `C0,100 450,0  900,100 ` где 450,0   это центр svg по оси Х а Ноль это по оси Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все изображения в формате PNG и у них достаточно качественно вырезан фон, то не вижу препятствий в использовании лишь CSS для решения:

```css
/* Only fo demo */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);background-position:0% 0%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;gap:1em}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  height: 45vh;
  width: 45vh;
  border: 10px solid #ff8f17;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1a1d6e;
}

.avatar img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 150%;
  width: inherit;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  object-fit: cover;
  border: inherit;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 150% 150% / 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/b/77-770414_a-group-of-community-people-peanut-butter-and.png" alt="">
</div>
```

То же относится и к фону с простыми скруглениями:

```css
/* Only fo demo */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);background-position:0% 0%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto}

footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 358px;
  background-image: url('https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/b/29-291730_happy-people-image-happy-people-transparent-background-clipart.png'), radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 100%, #f08f02 70%, #f08f0200 calc(70% + 3px));
  background-size: auto 100%, 200% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% calc(100% + 40px), 50% 0;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1d6e;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</footer>
```

Никаких псевдоэлементов и SVG. Используйте технологии по назначению.